# GET Error 410 (Gone): Express request param breaks route

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, rest, http

I have the following routes:

```ts
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(
    // ...
  );
  next();
});

app.get("/api/format/:videoId", (req, res, next) => {
  const videoId = req.params["videoId"];

  // ...
});

app.use(errorMiddleware)
```

If I make the following request

```ts
this.httpClient.get(
  `http://localhost:8000/api/format/vNjYpnJgN54`
)
```

I get the error

```ts
GET http://localhost:8000/api/format/vNjYpnJgN54 410 (Gone)
```

and no route or middleware seems to be hit. The `app.get` route is not even entered, error interception does not work, etc. **In fact, express is not even throwing any errors in the backend, I get only above `GET` error in frontend.**

If I append `_`, that is `videoId = "vNjYpnJgN54_"` it's working as expected.

I have the same problem with `videoId = "sFl_uR5tplw"`. I really don't see what could be wrong with those ids, I have different ids ending with a number that do work.

I also tried using `encodeURI(Component)`, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you've provided, it's not really possible to tell what's causing the 410 HTTP Code, because basic logic looks fine.

I can only guess that actually your route is handling the request, otherwise express would return (by default) status 404 if there is no route which could handle it. The following logic, which is missing in the snippet, could return status 410. Did you actually check (by using debugger or console logging at the start of the route) that it's not being used?

Comment: Yes, I verified via console.log statement that the request handler is not entered. I also tried adding a kind of route fallback, which isn't entered either...

Comment: I have replicated your logic on my device and everything is working correctly. The videoId's you have provided aren't causing any problems. The issue must be caused by something what's missing in the provided code snippet. If you say that the request handler is not even entered, I guess you should check all of your middlewares.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was indeed not with express but with Angular HttpClient. I posted an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was with frontend (Angular) caching: The videoId in question did once cause a 410 error and it seems after that the GET request has never been retried. I don't know if that makes any sense, but after disabling Angular HttpClient caching everything is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

To get params in ExpressJS, do the following

```
app.get("/api/format/:videoId", (req, res, next) => {
  const videoId = req.params.videoId;
  console.log(videoId)
  // ...
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: But that's what I'm doing...

Comment: As what I checked the videoId is not creating any issue. You must check your routes, middleware, and also check other routes matching to your route nearly and change the places of the routes.

Comment: Also try query params url instead of route params: like `app.get("/api/format")` so you have to send the videoId as `http://localhost:8000/api/format?videoId=vNjYpnJgN54`